# NGINX and cron - Permission denied to run script

Tags: php, cron

The scripts that help maintain my website (Debian + NGINX) are owned by "www-data".

The user that runs the cron jobs is "admin" (or root?)

I am logged in as admin and I cannot execute the script owned by www-data although the "admin" is a member of "www-data". (permission denied).

How can I allow my cron job to execute the script owned by www-data?

Comment: cron jobs run as the user that created the job. not all jobs run as root. and there is no standard "admin" user on a unix system, unless you're talking about root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I simply:

```
sudo crontab -e -u www-data
```

and made the cron job run as www-data. Now it seems the cron job is running my script without access problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the permission to 0775. This is the best way.

Comment: and what happens when the file gets re-created by the source control? I have to manually do that every time? I need something else what just enables root to execute the www-data owned script